# How to hide elements that have content using grid areas in CSS?

Tags: css, html, css-grid

I'm creating a basic web layout in CodePen to better understand how grid areas work with the CSS Grid module. It turns out that using the `.` notation doesn't actually "hide" the items, when applied to the `grid-template-areas` property.

Please see my code here: https://codepen.io/isaacasante/pen/KZmyKV

You can see that I'm leaving the grid cells below my menu empty, but the `section` element on which I've added `grid-area: random` still shows in the bottom right corner of my layout (below my footer).

Do you guys have any idea how I can get rid of it without removing the HTML? I want to use Grid Areas only, to hide it. I noticed that an easy solution is for me to set the padding on the `section` element to 0, but this isn't a good solution, because it won't work the next time I'm trying to "hide" an element that has content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You could reset** the grid-templates-rows to `grid-template-rows: 70px 40px 0px 290px 50px;`
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMNpaJ  and set `display:none` to `section.item`. `position:absolute;right:100vw`works to to lay it out of screen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpmdzj **But that is when** you know it is empty or is to be hidden any times.

**Instead** you can use `:empty` and `auto`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXjyLV so it is hidden only when empty.

**In fine**, the `grid-gap` remains visible. It can be reset to `0` and `margin` on `.item` might help along the `:empty` selector and `auto` value for this specific row:
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXjyLV

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: none`:

```
section.item {
    display: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9qLydrq/)

Comment: the problem is that because the grid area holds the space, even if you set display to none, the space will not collapse.